# Can JavaScript change my CSS class in the page on client side after click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I got this piece of JavaScript and I want to fade in my `divs` by changing the class and letting this (new) CSS3 effect animate a fade in. I used `.click` and `.fadeToogle` before but this lags far too much. CSS3 animation should be much better on the mobile phone if you read all the discussion about the *setTimer* thing and CSS3 Animations. (I'm doing this as a hybrid app on phonegapp so yes it's really laggy!)

This code works to show my div when clicked but fails to read the new class it gets assigned and doesn't close the div again. Here is the JavaScript/jQuery code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#stylesButtonImg").click(function() {
    if ($('#styles').hasClass("closed")) {
      $('#styles').removeClass('closed');
      $('#styles').addClass('open');
    } else if ($('#styles').hasClass("open")) {
      $('#styles').removeClass('open');
      $('#styles').addClass('close');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#styles {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.95);
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
.closed{display:none;}
.open{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="stylesButtonImg">click me</button>
<div id="styles" class="closed">
    <?php include 'styles.php';?>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you're using jQuery. Why not simply use toggleClass instead of add/removeClass?

Comment: i read that that was taken away and the .toggle effect only works with visible elements but my div is displayed as none so not "grabbable". That's how I understand it @Aer0

Comment: Could you wrap your example into a short fiddle? I actually don't think that this won't work.

Comment: If your using JQuery ( which it appears you are ) move your functions that manipulate the DOM into the document.ready function. That way you are sure its all been rendered before you attempt to manipulate it.

$( document ).ready(function() {
    //You call your function here
});   This should have been a comment, not the answer.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lemkztk/1/ @Aer0 didn't work :/

Comment: I see thanks for the hint :) @MisterPositive

Answer (score 3):

Don't use display:none, as that can't be animated.  Use opacity instead, which is animatable.  Also, toggleClass will flip between open/closed for you rather than you having to check and flip yourself.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#stylesButtonImg").click(function() {
    $('#styles').toggleClass('open', 'closed');
  });
});
```

```css
#styles {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.95);
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
.closed {
  opacity: 0;
}
.open {
  opacity: 1;
}
#stylesButtonImg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="stylesButtonImg">click me</button>
<div id="styles" class="closed">
  <?php include 'styles.php';?>
</div>
```

Comment: If the OP uses opacity, won't it keep the blank space on his page instead of letting other DOM elements use that space when it's 'hidden'?

Comment: This is close to what I need but I really can't change away from having it displayed as none because of having a complete dynamic webpage where I don't refresh and every "page" is in the index.php file but diplayed as none so the whole structure doesn't shift because of the space visibility creats :/

Comment: @James While your statement is correct, his design should take into consideration that manipulating properties like `display`, in elements that remain in the normal flow of the document, will cause redrawing in the browser. That is what is causing the lag. Sticking to `opacity`, `visibility` and `transform` is ideal when dealing with transitions and animations in CSS to achieve 60 FPS.

Comment: @James The element is already positioned absolute, so it is already out of the normal flow, but Ricky_Ruiz's comment about using forward animations can solve additional problems where the element needs to be out of the drawing context completely (or moved at the very end).

Comment: This was my original goal :) I wanted to be able to change the class so that i later on could animate the content with jquery but first i needed some way to "toggle" with the same button and there the adding and removing of the classes should be helping me :) @Ricky_Ruiz

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest using

```
$(function() {
  $("#stylesButtonImg").click(function() {
if ($('#styles').is(":visible")) {
  $('#styles').hide(time);
} else {
  $('#styles').show(time);
}
});
});
```

where `time` is the amount of time you want the hide/show animation to take in milliseconds (0 if you don't want animation). You also don't need the css if you do this.

Might as well use all of jquery's power if you're gonna use it.

Comment: I tried this but this still lags to much for using a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge or iPhone 6 :/ @Dec Sander

Answer (score 1):

Following on @Robert McKee [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348162/4305494).

I will quote the OP comment:

> I really can't change away from having it displayed as none because of
>   having a complete dynamic webpage where I don't refresh and every
>   "page" is in the index.php file but diplayed as none so the whole
>   structure doesn't shift because of the space visibility creats...

---

When forced to use `display: none;` what can be done is use an `animation` instead.

The `.close` and `.open` classes will still be used:

```
.closed {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
  animation: activePage 1s forwards;
}
```

Notice how now we use an animation in the `.open` class, which purpose is to animate from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1;`, using forwards as a value in the [**`animation-fill-mode`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property to keep the styles after the `animation` ends:

```
@keyframes activePage {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#stylesButtonImg").click(function() {
    $('#styles').toggleClass('open', 'closed');
  });
});
```

```css
#styles {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.95);
}
.closed {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
  animation: activePage 1s forwards;
}
#stylesButtonImg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2
}
@keyframes activePage {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="stylesButtonImg">click me</button>
<div id="styles" class="closed">
  <?php include 'styles.php';?>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Because the `animation` is removed on `.closed` class, when toggling back to close the "view", there will be no animation.

To solve this issue, we might need to take this further with JS.

The solution I will provide may have to be cleaned and/or improved by you, its objective is to guide you in the right direction.

Using the [**jQuery.fn.extend()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) method we will toggle between states on click. When the animation is finished it will toggle the classes `.open` and `.closed`.

The animations will be set with:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}
.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$.fn.extend({
  switchView: function() {
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

    var activeAnimationName = "fadeIn",
      inactiveAnimationName = "fadeOut",
      activeState = "open",
      inactiveState = "closed";

    var toggleState = function(el, animationName, currentState) {
      var $this = $(el);
      $this.removeClass(currentState);
      $this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
        $this.removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        if (currentState === inactiveState) {
          $this.addClass(activeState);
        } else {
          $this.addClass(inactiveState);
        }
      });
    }

    if (this.hasClass(inactiveState)) {
      toggleState(this, activeAnimationName, inactiveState);
    } else {
      toggleState(this, inactiveAnimationName, activeState);
    }
  }
});
$(function() {
  $("#stylesButtonImg").click(function() {
    $('#styles').switchView();
  });
});
```

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}
#styles {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.95);
}
.closed {
  display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
}
#stylesButtonImg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}
.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="stylesButtonImg">click me</button>
<div id="styles" class="closed">
  <?php include 'styles.php';?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is works beautifuly! I still got the same button displayed though which should act as a toggle back and when i click the same button (#stylesButtonImg) it flashes up and fades down in one millisec or something :/ It doesn't fade out as well as it fades in. The snippet which you created shows the same effect :O

Comment: @Zoung I have edited my answer, if you have any doubts in the implementation let me know.

Comment: Yes this looks promesing, never heard of this jQuery.fn.extended() method before so thanks for sharing :D ! @Ricky_Ruiz I chose however to take another way to get the hoped effect and I explained everything in an answer to this my own question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fading in and out through css is done by `opacity`. Your css seems to be wrong at the point where you're defining `display: none;` and `display: block;`. You may change those options through `opacity: 1;` and `opacity: 0;`

Your css should like that:

```
#styles {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

.closed {
  //  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.open {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

You can also clean up your whole JS code with just a single line inside of your click function.

```
  $("#stylesButtonImg").click(function() {
    $('#styles').toggleClass('closed', 'open');
  });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lemkztk/3/)

Comment: Yes, but i can't change from display none because of the website being a dynamical webpage where every page is loaded by a mousclick and all these none displayed layers whould destroy the webpages layout when the whitespaces come in and block space of other divs. :O

Answer (score 0):

Update!

I didn't make it work with the display property on none but I changed it to the visibility property. As the comments pointed out were the elements assignd to a absolute position which takes the elements(div's) out of he usual order. I then added the overflow:hidden property to hide the scrollbars and the invisible space which i thought was there but never was.

This is the code I use for now:

```
.closed{
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.open{
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility:visible;
 }
#styles{
    transition: .20s linear;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.95);
}
```

I got this html code for my picture buttons which work as toggles:

```
<div id="styles" class="closed">
    <?php include 'styles.php';?>
</div>
```

And this is my javascript which changes the classes so no unececery javascript is execudet and the css, which is supportet by mobile phones hardware acceleration, works much faster and consistent this way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#stylesButtonImg").click(function() {
            //The div which gets shown.
            $('#styles').toggleClass('open', 'closed');

            //All my other buttons who get faded out if they are active when i want to open the, in this case, styles page.
            $('#rateableUserProfile').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
            $('#profile').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
            $('#options').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
            $('#savedStyles').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
            $('#camera').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
        });
    });
});
```